# Save page after redirect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

So I'm using most recent react-router and i have two pages. On the first one I select id and after pressing the button I get redirected to '/user/:id' endpoint. How can I store the state of the previous page. For example I press back button in my browser and I want to get back to the page with the user id selected in the form. Can I do it without using redux? Is there something for that inside react router?

Comment: Hi, interesting, you could change the browser history location, perhaps this would be of interest https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/history.md

Comment: you only want to use react router, or you just want to avoid redux ? and if the second for what reason.

Comment: Mostly avoid redux. Firsly because it would be weird to set it up just for that cause, secondly I personally don't like redux, because it messes up the structure of the app. But if there isn't any easier way for this case I guess i'll just use it